# How i can get image from gallery in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

i am develop app in Blackberry which have photo functionality. i want to get photo from gallery and show it on Bitmap field. does any body have idea for this please send me.
thanx in advance..

Comment: Check this link. May be helpful to you.
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-can-I-add-image-to-galery-and-view-it-from-BlackBerry-Media/td-p/333842

Comment: Use filePicker to get the images form the SDCard; and show it on screen;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **FilePicker** is the main concept; I am taking the SDCard images. So, before testing set the sdcard in simulator;

Try this sample code:

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.picker.FilePicker;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.picker.FilePicker.Listener;

public class FilePickerScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener
{       
Bitmap bitmap;
ButtonField click;
BitmapField bitmapField;
public FilePickerScreen()
{   
    setTitle("FilePicker Screen");
    createGUI();
}

private void createGUI() 
{   
    add(new LabelField("Click to select the image", Field.FIELD_HCENTER));
    click=new ButtonField("Click");
    click.setChangeListener(this);
    add(click);         
    bitmapField=new BitmapField();
    add(bitmapField);
}   

private Bitmap getTheImage(String url) 
{
    Bitmap bitmap=null,scaleBitmap=null;
    InputStream inputStream=null;
    FileConnection fileConnection=null;     
    try
    {
        fileConnection=(FileConnection) Connector.open(url);
        inputStream=fileConnection.openInputStream();           
        byte[] data=new byte[(int)fileConnection.fileSize()];           
        data=IOUtilities.streamToBytes(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        fileConnection.close();
        bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmapFromBytes(data,0,data.length,1);

        //You can return this bitmap otherwise, after this you can scale it according to your requirement; like...
        scaleBitmap=new Bitmap(150, 150);
        bitmap.scaleInto(scaleBitmap, Bitmap.FILTER_LANCZOS);           
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        try 
        {
            if(inputStream!=null)
            {
                inputStream.close();                
            }
            if(fileConnection!=null)
            {
                fileConnection.close();
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception exp) 
        {

        }
        scaleBitmap=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("noimage.png");//Your known Image;     
    }
    return scaleBitmap;
}

public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context)
{
    if(field==click)
    {
        try 
        {
            FilePicker filePicker;
            filePicker=FilePicker.getInstance();
            filePicker.setPath("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/pictures/");
            filePicker.setListener(new Listener() 
            {       
                public void selectionDone(String path)
                {
                    bitmapField.setBitmap(getTheImage(path));
                }
            });
            filePicker.show();//it show what ever you select.
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            StartUp.exceptionHandling(e.getMessage());
        }
    }       
}   
}
```

I think this may be your requirement;

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the your target OS version. I would suggest to use FilePicker API for 6.0+ (Actually it's available from 5.0 OS but has issues with some minor OS versions). And for lower OS versions I would suggest you to use this [article](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800256/How_To_-_Create_a_File_Selection_Popup_Screen.html?nodeid=1498743&vernum=0) to have your own implementation.